# it needs too long time to take effect for adding root admin permission to other using az ClL

Tags: azure-cli, azure-purview

use Azure CLI https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/purview/account?view=azure-cli-latest#az-purview-account-add-root-collection-admin to  add root collection admin permisson to others for purview account. Actually ,the use was added after executing command line ,but it needs almost one hour to take effect. this doesn't make sense

Answer (score 0):

I have been using purview for quite sometime but never faced the issue with collection admin permissions reflects in 1+hour. It happens instantly.

If you still having issues, I suggest you to raise a support ticket.